# dispatchEvent all elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to dispatch on all elements?

For exemple, we can do `window.dispatchEvent(evt)`, but I want to allow all elements to use the event. (for onclick, we can use almost all element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(elem){
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: Why didn't you write `document.getElementsByTagName("*").forEach(function(elem){elem.dispatchEvent(evt);});`?

Comment: @user1365010 because `.forEach` is a generic `Array` method which I'm borrowing to be used with a `NodeList`. `NodeList` doesn't have that method.

Comment: Just to say, I created a way (based on yours) that is 30% speedier than yours : http://jsperf.com/foreach-or-other-method-with-a-for-loop (But your answer really helped me)

Comment: @user1365010 obviously hand written loop is much faster, but when writing answers, micro optimizations are usually not the goal